# BLL Logical - Data Access pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I have this situation ( MVC + EF )

I have two tables Category and Product in Database.

Initlialy, I create a BLL for Category. The BBL have CRUD methods.

In the D ( Delete ). This method will delete an category by ID.

So. Everything about Category BBL is done.

Next, I create a BLL for Product. It also have CRUD methods.

In the C ( Create ) View. I show an HTML , That is a list of Category for products.

The problem I want to asks here:

When I add Product BLL to my Project. I have to modify the Delete method of Category BLL.

I have/want to add new method named DeleteProductByCategoryID() to an BBL. And I call it in Delete method of Category BLL.

```
public void Delete(int id)
{
xxxxx.DeleteProductByCategoryID(id);
categoryBLL.DeleteCategory(id);
}
```

The method will delete all Product of specified Category ID.

So the question is: Where Should I create the DeleteProductByCategoryID() method  ( Category or Product BLL) ?

To show a list of Category in Controller.Product.Create() view, I also want to create a new method to get a Collection of Category.Should I put this method in Product BLL or Category BLL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a Product has (at least) one Category and not otherwise. Does product deletion through categoryId make sense (for example when a product is binded to more than one categories)?

But anyway, generally you do not want to create hard dependencies.

One possibility would be to create a **composite key table** in the Product DB, that holds all possible **CategoryId**'s for one **ProductId**. This way you have the connection between Product and Category, but you don't create any hard DB dependencies, because the table holds only values. This also simplifies the CRUD operations. Often such composite tables are named like this: **Entity1_has_Entity2**.

```
[Product_has_Category]
[ProductId] PK, NOT NULL
[CategoryId] PK, NOT NULL
```

Filled for ProductId 1 in Category 10, 13 and 5:

```
[1, 10]
[1, 13]
[1, 5]
```

In this case the **delete** method should be placed in the ProductBLL and could look like this:

```
public void Delete(int id)
{
    // delete the _has_ relations - there is no connection between product and category anymore
    productBLL.DeleteCategoriesForProduct(id);
    productBLL.DeleteProduct(id);
}
```

The **show** method in the ProductBLL will be also simple:

```
public void ShowCategoriesForProduct(int id)
{
    // from the _has_ relations table
    List<int> categoryIds = productBLL.CategoriesForProduct(id);
    foreach (int categoryId in categoryIds)
    {
        var categoryName = categoryBLL.CategoryInfo(categoryId).Name;
    }
}
```

I would have classified the problem rather to database normalization than design patterns. One good example about DB normalization can be found in [this article](http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/).

Comment: productBLL.CategoriesForProduct(id); Above method is redundant code. The Category BLL created first. Thus, the GetCategories() existed in Category BLL. In Product BLL should we create new method or create new Category instance and call GetCategories() ?

Comment: @Giang My suggestion introduces one new table in order to enable easy **n to n** relation between Product and Category. I don't think, that the code is redundant. What do you mean exactly by "The Category BLL created first"? In the method **ShowCategoriesForProduct** are fetched only the categories to which the product is assigned to and not **all** possible categories. If you just call categoryBLL.GetCategories() then how would you know which category to show for the currently selected product?